# ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm grabbing product versions from DB which stores as `VARCHAR` and has value something like this `2.6.12-build.222`. I need to trim everything after `-` so the result is `2.6.12` below is the code how I'm doing this string operation and working perfectly fine, I'm getting trimmed version but I need to compare two versions for the further operations for that I'm using `Version` class but as soon as I pass my substring to Version class it's showing me this error-

```
ArgumentException: Version string portion was too short or too long.
```

All my versions are in `2.6.12` format

```
var resourceGuids = httpResp.Select(xl => xl.guid).ToList();

var existingBuilds = _DBcontext.Deployedproducts.Where(xl => resourceGuids.Contains(xl.Guid.ToString())).ToList();

var x = existingBuilds.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Guid == item.guid);

Version v = new Version(x.ProductVersion.Substring(0, x.ProductVersion.LastIndexOf("-") + 1).Replace(@"-",""));

if (item.Item1.version < v)
{
    x.LatestMajorRelease = item.Item1.version.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `+ 1` in `Substring` and you won't need the `Replace`.  Note however if there is no dash your code will result in an empty string.

Comment: oh no  I cannot do that some versions are without any dash so it will return empty string

Comment: If there are some without a dash then you need to check if `LastIndexOf` returns -1 and in that case you don't want to do the Substring at all.

Comment: Your problem is that if there is no dash you are trying to create a `Version` from an empty string, thus the error about not having enough portions.  It expects 2 to 4 numbers separated by periods.

Comment: ohhh now I get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can have values without a dash you have to check for that before doing the substring.

```
string version = x.ProductVersion;
int dashIndex = x.ProductVersion.IndexOf("-");
if(dashIndex > -1)
    version = version.Substring(0, dashIndex);

Version v = new Version(version);
```

Note I used `IndexOf` just in case there's a second dash later on.

You could also do other checks like if `dashIndex` is 0 then this will result in an empty string as it's likely an invalid version to begin with.

In fact if `dashIndex` is less than 3 then it cannot be a valid version (as the version requires at least 2 parts like 1.1 or 2.3).